# Apache2 set up multiple site with subdomain not working?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, wordpress, subdomain, lamp

I want to run 2 Wordpress sites on my VPS installed LAMP stack.
Site 1: `test1.example.com`
Site 2: `test2.example.com`

Here are my config files:

`test1.example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test1.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/test1
    <Directory "/path/test1">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`test2.example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/test2
    <Directory "/path/test2">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I did `a2ensite` for both configs files and restarted the apache2 service.

But the problem is the domain `test2.example.com` and `example.com` (not set up yet) automatic redirect to `test1.example.com`. I also check config for database of site2 and it's correct. When I `a2dissite` `test1.example.com.conf` domain `test2.example.com` work fine

Here is `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /reeme/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /reeme/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: "automatic redirect" - is it actually a "redirect" - as in an external HTTP redirect? ie. Do you see a 3xx response code to your original request? That would certainly change the focus of this question. Bit of an aside, but you shouldn't be using `Order` and `Allow` directives on Apache 2.4

Comment: Yes, it return code 301.

Comment: If you are seeing a 301 redirect then that would strongly suggest an issue with WordPress - unless there is a redirect elsewhere in your server config (there is no redirect in the code you have posted). However, if `tes2.example.com` works when you disable `test1.example.com` suggests the issue is elsewhere in the server config? Are you sure the redirect is from `test2.example.com` to `test1.example.com`?

Comment: "the domain `test2.example.com` and `example.com` (not set up yet) automatic redirect to `test1.example.com`" - That would seem to suggest the request is not matching the vhost and is simply defaulting to the first one defined? But that would not trigger a 3xx redirect. There would seem to be _something else_ going on here?

Comment: It is weird. It has some problem with my server config, not Wordpress. Those are all my config files. I don't config redirect elsewhere.